# Crop image in R to eliminate heterogeneous background

Tags: r, image-processing

Does `R` have the ability to auto-crop or segment images like this to get rid of the heterogeneous background and isolate the turtle in the picture?  This particular photo is in `jpg` format.  Perhaps that can be changed if doing so would be helpful.

[image]

Comment: Please have a look on: https://forloopsandpiepkicks.wordpress.com/2021/04/09/image-segmentation-in-r-automatic-background-removal-like-in-a-zoom-conference/

Comment: You could explore the package [`magick`](https://docs.ropensci.org/magick/articles/intro.html), I've no idea if it's able to do things like this.